# What is the best way to create variables from a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

To be able to increase my dictionary while not changing much else in the code, I want to iterate through the dictionary keys and create dataframes.

The way I have found is through creating global variables with global(). However, is this the most pythonic way, or the best way? I know global variables are a nono, but it seems to be the only fix here.

```
stocks = {
    'Tencent':'TCEHY',
    'Blizzard' : 'ATVI',
    'EA':'EA',
    'Rockstar':'TTWO'
}

def create_dataframes(stock_dict):
    for stock in stock_dict:
        globals()[stock] = pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(stock_dict[stock]))
```

This results in new variables with the key names, which is of course what I want. I just want to know if I should do this in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: you could easily use the dictionary directly

Comment: The most pythonic way is to use dictionary for dynamic names, and not create globals in runtime.

Comment: @Netwave What do you mean with using it directly? I'm loading the variables with a full dataframe, so I can further analyze them with their respective names.

Comment: @Dansekongen, exactly what bereal said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create global variables at runtime, just use a dictionary.

```
dfs = {}
for stock_name, stock_code in stock_dict.items():
    dfs[stock_name] = pd.read_csv(f'{stock_code}.csv')
```

You can then access them using their names

```
dfs['EA'].describe()
```